# View.center Returning Point Outside of View

Tags: ios, swift, centering

I have a UILabel that is in the view controller (With Constraints).

I'm trying to add a custom switch to the view in the same place as the Label so I use label.center to get the label center point and apply it to the switch.

The problem is that I cant see the switch when I run the app and I can't figure out why.

This the code I use:

```
var material = MaterialSwitch(size: MaterialSwitchSize(0, 0, 22))
    material.setup(delegate: self)
    material.center = self.label.center
    material.thumbOnColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.59, blue:0.53, alpha:1.0)
    material.trackOnColor = UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.76, blue:0.73, alpha:1.0)
    material.thumbOffColor = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.95, blue:0.95, alpha:1.0)
    material.trackOffColor = UIColor(red:0.69, green:0.69, blue:0.69, alpha:1.0)
    self.view.addSubview(material)
```

Comment: I don't know your view hierarchy but have you tried to bring the view to front as well? self.view.bringSubviewToFront(material)

Comment: No it didn't help...

Comment: does this have a frame somewhere in it's class definition?

Comment: yes in the init(), why?

Comment: how is it that you say you are using constraints when I don't see that you've declared the "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE", if you ARE NOT setting this value to false then you won't see your label, EVER since the label will be pegged at the top left of your window with a window size of CGRect(0,0,0,0)

Comment: Show more code, show the entire code for the label, and I'll show you an answer.

Comment: If you use constraints, then you must set the "translatesAutoResizingMaskintoConstraints" to false, if you DON"T use constraints, then you must set a frame for the UI element. You can sort of mix the two if you know what you are doing, but this woudl take some vry very advanced code and given this quesiton you are asking, I'm not sure you are there yet, so stick with either constrints and making that setting false or stick to frames where in the layout subview methods you set a frame